# Firestore "where" and "orderBy" conflict

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting below when error when using "where" and "orderBy" together, and I have indexed both fields already. I want to show only documents where visibility only value with "public" and mean time I want to sort them by createdAt before passing to GridView !!

```
Future getPosts() async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore
        .collection('Listings')
        .where('visibility', isEqualTo: 'public')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .get(); 
    return querySnapshot.docs;
  }
```

Error I am getting:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#f6bd7):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<dynamic>
package:lankanmotorslk/…/TEST_SCREENS/listView_listings.dart:66
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _ListPageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:lankanmotorslk/…/TEST_SCREENS/listView_listings.dart:96
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:775
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4691
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: What line was the error pointing at? Please post the full error code.

Comment: Hey Victor, full error message added..

Comment: Great please include the code of the `FutureBuilder`, looks like the error is coming from there.

Comment: Hey Victor, I read that cannot use "where" and "orderBy" together. If I remove either one, it's working fine. But I want to use both 